# Filtering a very large list of domains using slice

Tags: python, string, slice

I'm filtering a very large list of subdomains and I'm trying to create a variable slice. The list is extremely large so I want to approach this in the most "pythonic" method that would be performance optimised.

The method works like  the following:

Assuming a list of domains taking a variety of formats:

```
a.b.c.domain.com
d.e.domain.com
f.domain.com
```

If the user wants to filter by a depth of one, only domains that are formatted like `f.domain.com` would be displayed. If the user selects a depth of two, domains formatted like both `f.domain.com` and `d.e.domain.com` would be shown.

I believe this could be accomplished with something like `s.join(a.split(".")[len(a.split(".")) - 4:])` however it seems overly complicated and I was wondering if there's a way of using slice that I'm missing which is ideal for this kind of use case?

Comment: just to be clear your asking how to group the domain names by the number of seperate '.' prefixes there are from 'domain.com'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it -

```
domains = [
"a.b.c.domain.com",
"d.e.domain.com",
"f.domain.com" ]

def filter_domains(domains, n):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x.count('.') <= n+1, domains))

print (filter_domains(domains, 2))
# prints ["d.e.domain.com", "f.domain.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about performance, but similar to @PrasadK's answer:

```
dl = [
    "a.b.c.domain.com",
    "d.e.domain.com",
    "f.domain.com"
]
N = 2

print([x for x in dl if x.count(".")-1 <= N])
# prints ["d.e.domain.com", "f.domain.com"]
```

The above can easily be converted to a generator, if your list is too long (depends also on how you load the domains)